# Applying Jquery jScrollPane as soon as scrollbar appears

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am using Jquery jScrollPane to improve the look of a vertical scrollbar on a div in one of my pages. The problem is that at the moment when the page loads the scrollbar first appears looking like the standard chunky scrollbars you would normally expect to see for a second or two before jScrollPane is applied and neatens things up.

Obviously it would look a lot better if the scrollbar just appeared in the nice formatted way jScrollPane makes it right from the moment the scrollbar appears. I've been playing around with it and trying to find an answer via google but am getting nowhere so thought I'd ask here if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this one but does it work if you hide the div, call the jScrollPane method and then show it after? I have a feeling that hiding it will mess up the overflow calculations but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Good Idea. I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately it wouldn't show properly after unhiding it.